# Pattern for helping with code duplication

Tags: php, design-patterns, duplicates

Recently I wrote a verification that catches exceptions and prevents the DB from persisting any data in that case. This piece of code seems like it's going to be used extensively in my code. So it raises a question: the begin of the code and end of it are alwas the same, the only thing that changes is what's in the middle. In this case, is there a pattern for not repeting it all the way in my code?

```
public function createGroupWith($data)
  {
    try {
      DB::beginTransaction();

      $modules_id = array_pop($data);

      $group = Group::create($data);
      $group->modules()->attach($modules_id);

      DB::commit();
      return ['msg' => trans('cms.groups.success_create')];
    } catch (\Throwable $error) {
      DB::rollBack();
      return ['msg' => $error->getMessage()];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Make your function accepting a callback and pass that in. Then you can execute it inside.

Comment: I assume by duplicate code you mean the try/catch and transactions? It is pretty common to type these out in each place you want them. You might find that you want to have a transaction without a try/catch or vice versa. Also, you can simply the transaction syntax  by using `DB::transaction(function () { your_code_here });` That will handle the commit/rollback automatically.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a skeleton of methods and you want to override behaviour sometimes, then you can try to use `Template Method` pattern. As wiki says about [`Template method` pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

> the template method is one of the behavioral design patterns
> identified by Gamma et al.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) in the book Design Patterns. The
> template method is a method in a superclass, usually an abstract
> superclass, and defines the skeleton of an operation in terms of a
> number of high-level steps. These steps are themselves implemented by
> additional helper methods in the same class as the template method.

I am sorry, I do not know php, but give me a try to implement it.

```
abstract class Your class
{
    abstract protected function overridableBehaviour();     

    /** Template method */
    public final createGroupWith($data)
    {
        try {
          DB::beginTransaction();

          $this->overridableBehaviour();

          DB::commit();
          return ['msg' => trans('cms.groups.success_create')];
        } catch (\Throwable $error) {
          DB::rollBack();
          return ['msg' => $error->getMessage()];
        }
    }
}
```

It is possible to see [php code example here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern#PHP_example):

```
abstract class Game
{
    abstract protected function initialize();
    abstract protected function startPlay();
    abstract protected function endPlay();

    /** Template method */
    public final function play()
    {
        /** Primitive */
        $this->initialize();

        /** Primitive */
        $this->startPlay();

        /** Primitive */
        $this->endPlay();
    }
}
```

and its concrete implementations:

```
class Mario extends Game
{
    protected function initialize()
    {
        echo "Mario Game Initialized! Start playing.", PHP_EOL;
    }

    protected function startPlay()
    {
        echo "Mario Game Started. Enjoy the game!", PHP_EOL;
    }

    protected function endPlay()
    {
        echo "Mario Game Finished!", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

and:

```
class Tankfight extends Game
{
    protected function initialize()
    {
        echo "Tankfight Game Initialized! Start playing.", PHP_EOL;
    }

    protected function startPlay()
    {
        echo "Tankfight Game Started. Enjoy the game!", PHP_EOL;
    }

    protected function endPlay()
    {
        echo "Tankfight Game Finished!", PHP_EOL;
    }    
}
```

and:

```
$game = new Tankfight();
$game->play();

$game = new Mario();
$game->play();
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, thanks. But I don't know if this would work in the case for a a try catch block, because they would need to be saparated in start and end functions, what isn't allowed I think. But thanks anyways

Comment: @BernardoBeniniFantin in my view, I do not know php, but when we use inheritance then it should be returned into `try catch` block of base class and overridable methods will be executed in child classes

Comment: Could you provide an example, please? I didn't get what you said about inheritance.

Comment: @BernardoBeniniFantin I mean that control will be started from base class and when control will meet overridable child method, then control will go to child method. You can debug wiki example from my reply and see what I mean :)